# Rails: admin routes to manage non-admin models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having a problem trying to configure rails for managing non-admin models using 'admin' namespaced routes. For example, a `Widget` model would normally have a RESTful route at `/widgets` with a controller called `WidgetsController`, I have a routes file that namespaces the routes and controller:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :widgets
end

class Admin::WidgetsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @widgets = ::Widget.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end
  ...etc...
end
```

In the views I am getting an error when I try to use the route method for create:

```
<% @widgets.each do |widget| %>
  <%= link_to 'Show', admin_widget(widget) %>
<% end %>
```

Error:

```
undefined method `admin_widget'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I was missing `path` at the end of the method name. It should have been:

```
admin_widget_path(widget)
```

instead of `admin_widget`